# Kube-dns does not resolve external hosts on kubeadm bare-metal cluster

Tags: kubernetes

I've got a k8n cluster setup on a bare-metal ubuntu 16.04 cluster using weave networking with kubeadm.  I'm having a variety of little problems, the most recent of which is that I realized that kube-dns does not resolve external addresses (e.g. google.com).  Any thoughts on why?  Using kube-adm did not give me a lot of insight into the details of that part of the setup.

Comment: Post definition of your kube-dns (pod, deployment, service, or whatever)?

Comment: Thanks for your comment.  I actually resolved this issue and will post the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that a node-level firewall was interfering with the cluster networking.  So there was no issue with the DNS setup.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, can you explain a little bit of how you solved this?

Comment: In my case I think the node's were just not able to talk with the DNS server server because I had a firewall setup that was blocking some kubernetes communication.  If you're using ufw check your ufw.log (in /var/logs) while you stop/start/access pods.  Let me know if I can help more.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to reply back. In my case the Kube-dns takes /etc/resolve.conf from my master so I had 127.0.1.1 pushed from local network as first nameserver which caused the issue. Once I resolved it, it is fixed. Hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on kubernetes v1.6 and it was not a firewall issue in my case.

The problem was that I have configured the DNS manually on the `/etc/docker/daemon.json`, and these parameters are not used by kube-dns. Instead it is needed to create a `configmap` for kubedns (pull request [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/41826) and documentation [here](https://www.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/)), as follows:

**Solution**

Create a `yaml` for the configmap, for example `kubedns-configmap.yml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: kube-dns
  namespace: kube-system
data:
  upstreamNameservers: |
    ["<own-dns-ip>"]
```

And simply, apply it on kubernetes with

```
kubectl apply -f kubedns-configmap.yml
```

**Test 1**

On your kubernetes host node:

```
dig @10.96.0.10 google.com
```

**Test 2**

To test it I use a busybox image with the following resource configuration (`busybox.yml`):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: busybox
spec:
    containers:
    # for arm
    #- image: hypriot/armhf-busybox
    - image: busybox
      command:
          - sleep
          - "3600"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
      name: busybox
    restartPolicy: Always
```

Apply the resource with

```
kubectl apply -f busybox.yml
```

And test it with the following:

```
kubectl exec -it busybox -- ping google.com
```